# Selecting columns AND a subclass with fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class (Project) that represents a somewhat large DB table.  I need to retrieve only about a dozen columns, in addition to a sub-class (ProjectUses, which represents another DB table with a 1:1 relationship with Project).  I am able to get the single columns of a Project object just fine using projections as seen below, but am having problems also retrieving an object of Project with the ProjectUses subclass populated.  Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Here is the repository code I am using:

```
public Project GetProjectDebenture(int pkProjectID)
{
    var proj = _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Project))
                .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                    .Add(Projections.Property("pkProjectID"), "pkProjectID")
                    .Add(Projections.Property("ReservePercentage"), "ReservePercentage")
                    .Add(Projections.Property("FundingFeePercentage"), "FundingFeePercentage")
                    .Add(Projections.Property("PackagingFeePercentage"), "PackagingFeePercentage")
                    )
                .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(Project)))
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("pkProjectID", pkProjectID))
                .UniqueResult<Project>();
            return proj;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have tried using `Projections.Property("ProjectUses")` and `Projections.GroupProperty("ProjectUses")` to retrieve a populated subclass, but with no success.

And below is the [simplified] code for the class and mapping definitions

```
// Project class
public partial class Project
{
    public int pkProjectID { get; set; }
    public decimal ReservePercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal FundingFeePercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal PackagingFeePercentage { get; set; }
    public ProjectUses ProjectUses { get; set; }
}

// ProjectUses class
public partial class ProjectUses
{
    public int pkProjectID { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    ...
}

// Project mapping
public class ProjectMap : ClassMap<Project>
{
    public ProjectMap()
    {
        Table(@"Project");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.pkProjectID)
          .Column("pkProjectID")
          .Not.Nullable()
          .GeneratedBy.Identity();
        ...
        HasOne<ProjectUses>(x => x.ProjectUses)
          .PropertyRef(r => r.Project)
          .Cascade.All();
    }
}
// Project Uses mapping
public class ProjectUsesMap : ClassMap<ProjectUses>
{
    public ProjectUsesMap()
    {
        Table(@"ProjectUses");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.pkProjectID, "pkProjectID").GeneratedBy.Foreign("Project");
        HasOne<Project>(x => x.Project)
            .Constrained()
            .ForeignKey()
            .Cascade.None();

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a DTO with all the properties you need and project from `Project` and `ProjectUses` onto the new DTO. This has the additional advantage of separating the view model from the domain model.

Comment: I ended up going with this method.  It was a little tricky getting some of the mappings to work to prevent getting the "More than one row with given identifier for class" error.  Like you said, creating a new domain object allowed me to get all similar info (from multiple tables) into one place, so now anything that has to do with numbers or money is encapsulated in its own class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.Not.LazyLoad()` in you ProjectMap class?

Comment: I have.  That works fine when all I am doing is a call such as `_session.Get<T>(_ID);`, and nhibernate uses the mappings to determine what to gather, but since I am using the Projections to specify data retrieval, it appears that all Lazy/NotLazy is ignored (which makes sense).  Thanks, though